# AVAssetWriter fails with H264 codec?

Tags: avfoundation, avassetwriter

I've gotten the following code to work just fine using an AppleProRes422 codec and an AVAssetWriter.

However, the code fails with NSError -12348 on the adapter should I use an H264 codec instead.

**I'm perplexed.**

```
AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
                              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoOutputPath] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                          error:&error];
NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                                nil];

NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecAppleProRes422, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               //AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey, // I use EITHER this key or the ProRes one
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:imageSize.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:imageSize.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               nil];

AVAssetWriterInput* videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                        assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                        outputSettings:videoSettings];


AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
                                                 assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput
                                                 sourcePixelBufferAttributes:outputSettings];
```

Later on, I grab the raw pixel data from the input file (a BGR-24 AVI file that's been converted to BGRA-32 data), and the NSError pops up with the -12348 error should I try to use the H264 codec in the output dictionary as opposed to the ProRes422 codec.

```
    unsigned char *buf = [myAsset readFileFrame:i];  // contains 32-bit pixel data

    CVPixelBufferRef pxBuffer = nil;
    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, [adaptor pixelBufferPool], &pxBuffer);
    if (status != kCVReturnSuccess){
        NSLog(@"Failed to create pixel buffer");
    }

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxBuffer, 0);
    unsigned char *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxBuffer);
    memcpy(pxdata,buf,imageSize.width*imageSize.height*4);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxBuffer, 0);

    free(buf);

    if (pxBuffer) {
        BOOL append_ok = NO;
        while (!append_ok) {
            if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)  {
                //print out status:
                NSLog(@"Processing video frame (%lu)",(unsigned long)i);
                CMTime presTime = CMTimeMake((int64_t)i,(int32_t) fps);
                append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:pxBuffer withPresentationTime:presTime];
                if(!append_ok){
                    NSError *error = videoWriter.error;
                    if(error!=nil) {
                        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@,%@.", error, [error userInfo]);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                printf("adaptor not ready %lu\n", (unsigned long)i);
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
            }
        }
        //CVPixelBufferRelease(pxBuffer);
    }
}

NSLog(@"**************************************************");

//Finish the session:
[videoWriterInput markAsFinished];
[videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler: ^{}];
```

The actual error produced is as follows:

> 2016-01-17 15:52:46.132 AVIConvert[8495:292526] Unresolved error Error
>   Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be
>   completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6280002423a0 {Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12348 "(null)"},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12348),
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed},{
>       NSLocalizedDescription = "The operation could not be completed";
>       NSLocalizedFailureReason = "An unknown error occurred (-12348)";
>       NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12348 \"(null)\"";

I thought that using some alternate output formats would work but, alas, no:

```
  kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB /* 32 bit ARGB */
  kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA /* 32 bit BGRA */
  kCVPixelFormatType_32ABGR /* 32 bit ABGR */
  kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA /* 32 bit RGBA */
```

**Can someone offer some insight?**

Comment: I can convert a video that's up to 8688 pixels in width using H.264.  It fails above that.  ProRes does not fail.